# jQuery.post and target div with google results

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, target

I want to use custom form and want to see results in target DIV('results').
So I tried to use ajax. But I don't know what is wrong.

Even this demo(https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) is not working correctly.
What should I do? I tried "http://www.google.com" and "hello.txt" in action.

```
<form action="/" id="searchForm">
  <input type="text" name="s" placeholder="Search...">
  <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
<div id="result"></div>

<script>
$( "#searchForm" ).submit(function( event ) {

  event.preventDefault();
  var $form = $( this ),
    term = $form.find( "input[name='s']" ).val(),
    url = $form.attr( "action" );

  var posting = $.post( url, { s: term } );

  posting.done(function( data ) {
    var content = $( data ).find( "#content" );
    $( "#result" ).empty().append( content );
  });
});
```

how can I have a results of google in target DIV? Should I use frameset or iframe?

**updates**

I post another question for framing. It has similar errors. Could you tell what can I try to do?

[html frameset with google results "SAMEORIGIN" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22874552/html-frameset-with-google-results-sameorigin-error)

Comment: Which server side language do you use? You can't pull data from other domain using javascript/jQuery, its kind of limitation of javascript.
What you can do is, you can do webpage scrapping (Google search, in your case) with any server side scripting language (Perl, PHP etc.) and then u can load data to `result` div

Comment: I used PHP. Please see the updates.

Answer (score 1):

Checking server side code.

can you share server side code ??

Once you log full response from server like

```
 posting.done(function( data ) {
    console.log(data);
    ...
  });
```

and check what you are searching( #content ) is really there in response, have made any syntax error in generating markup from server side code ?