# html frameset with google results "SAMEORIGIN" error

Tags: php, jquery, html

tried to use ajax to target div but it's not working. So now I try to use frameset like

```
<frameset border=0 rows="300, *">
    <frame src="search.html" name="top" target="bottom">
    <frame src="bottom.php"  name="bottom">
</frameset>
```

The search.html has a form, input and submit button. I wanted to see the results of google on bottom.

The bottom.php is below to redirect.

```
<?php  
   header( 'Location: http://www.google.com/scholar' ) ;
?>
```

Nytimes.com, bing.com and others are fine. But only google.com has "SAMEORIGIN" errors.

What is the best solution to have it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, perhaps consulting the product documentation for that error gives you insight about it? What did it say what the error signals? Why can't you rule out the source of the error? What did you do so far?

Answer (score 3):

As you've identified, Google prevents framing by sending a `x-frame-options:SAMEORIGIN` response header. Thus, Google pages cannot be framed except in pages from the same domain (`google.com`).

The `X-Frame-Options` response header is a security feature which cannot be bypassed in modern browsers.

**Reference**

- MDN - [`X-Frame-Options` response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options)
- Google Product Forums (2011) - [Is Google.com blocking IFraming all of a sudden?](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/websearch/pjHnvDST2D4)

---

If you want to implement Google search in your website, look into [Google Custom Search](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/).

Comment: Framing is not working, DIV (ajax, jQuery) is also not working for Cross Domain. Is it right?

Comment: Google does not allow framing their pages from different domains (`X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN`), Ajax by default does not work cross-domain due to the [Same-Origin Police](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy), which could be circumvented if the server would set [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) headers or provide a JSONP response format, but this is not the case with Google. If all that you want is your users to be able to perform a Google Scholar search, maybe you can put a link to open it in a popup window/new tab?

Comment: thanks for your comments. A link to open in a new tab is an alternative in mind. However, I wanted to make sure that whether framming and ajax are not able to use or not.

Comment: If I use a new tab, do you think is it possible to have an action button on google scholar in new tab? it will be same issues, right?

Comment: Not sure if I understood the "action button" part, but yes, your page won't be able to communicate with nor manipulate the Google page as their domains differ.

Comment: This is rather complex because the Google page clearly tells the browser "do not frame me under another domain" and the browser respects that. Ajax requests (and scripting through different windows) is only possible abiding the Same-Origin Police, or with CORS enabled. Maybe if you post another question with your requirements and what you have in mind, it will be easier to find a solution. `=]`

Comment: Okay very clear! thanks! never minds an action button. :) What if opening to new tab, is it possible to keep track/check a URL and parse it in previous tab to do something when the specific URL comes?

Comment: I believe you would need to access the [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location) of that tab, which is not possible as scripting is restricted by the Same-Origin Police. In layman's terms, you can say JavaScript in browsers is sandboxed: pages in different domains run in different sandboxes (unless permission is granted through CORS or whatnot). So, you can't read, write, listen, manipulate nor access data from a `window` whose page is from a different domain, and (AFAIK) none of workarounds apply to this case as previously said.

Comment: Hence, it seems like you have a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) -- your attempted solution will not work the way you want, you would probably get a better answer by asking a question explaining the *actual problem* that you are trying to solve.

Comment: Thanks! I will make new and refer to you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22896796/how-to-get-google-results-into-our-webpage-without-same-origin-policy