# How to get Google results into our webpage without SAME ORIGIN POLICY

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, same-origin-policy, google-scholar

We have own form in our webpage. We want to show google(`www.google.com/scholar`) results into our webpage. We tried

- `jQuery, Ajax`
- `HTML framing (iFrame, frameset)`

  and all of these have `SAMEORIGIN` issues.

We also tried using a `new tab` and found it has same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22874552/html-frameset-with-google-results-sameorigin-error) . All these solutions seem to work only with http://www.google.com/custom and no other google websites.

Is there any alternative to do so?

Comment: Use the [Google api](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer it myself. There are no solutions so far.

Answer (score 0):

Google prevents you from doing this. You could set up some server side code to scrape the results but this would almost definitely be blocked by Google. If this suits your needs you can create a form that submits your search to that page and opens it in a new tab like so:

```
<form action="http://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar" method="get" target="_blank">
  <input type="text" name="q">
  <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Live example here: http://jsfiddle.net/v8qG8/

**Update:**

I mentioned that Google would block the scraping of its services, however I just found the third party library which does that. Not sure on Google's opinion on it though. http://www.icir.org/christian/scholar.html

Comment: In that case, how can we obtain the URL of the google scholar page which the user is currently in? Can we track the google webpages which the user is navigating through?

Comment: Do you mean which search result the user has clicked through to? If so, you can't track that unless you used an api. There is a search API that @tekrat suggested but that is for web search and not Scholar.

Comment: @Ryan Thanks, we tried it. It's not answer what we're looking for now.

Comment: @Ryan We would like to track the URL of the google scholar webpage.

Comment: @Dinesh It's clear that what you're trying to do is unethical. There's a reason why Google blocks access via certain medium and allows others via their API. My suggestion: stop what you're doing and just provide a link to Google scholar.

Answer (score -1):

You may also want to look at Google's custom API.  You can get 100 free searches a day and then you pay $5 / 1000 search after that.  If you cache the results or do low volume this may work for you.

- Search API: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview
- All Google API's: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/

Comment: But there is no API for Google scholar.